# Solving for linear velocity

Tags: trigonometric-series

A wheel is rotating at 3 radians per second and the wheel has an 80 inch diameter
 To the nearest foot per minute, what is the linear velocity?

Answer (score 1):

The radius is $40 \text{ inches} = \frac{40}{12} \text{ feet}= \frac{10}3 \text{ ft}$ since $12 \text{ inches}=1\text{ foot}$. The wheel every second moves a distance equal to the arc length subtended by a $3$ radian angle on the wheel. The arc length is given by $3\cdot \frac{10}3\text{ feet}=10\text{ ft}$. So it moves $10 \text{ feet}$ in one second. The distance it moves in $1$ minute shouldn't be difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

V=r*W

where V= linear velocity, r= radius and W=angular velocity

but first you need to convert inches to foot

r= 40 inches = 10/3 foot

now V= r*W = 10/3 * 3 = 10 foot per sec

V= 600 foot per min

are you from US because never heard of using foot/min